# One dimensional motion problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, speed

I kept almost 2 hours trying to solve this problem :

> Two trains are 150 km apart. Train A moves at 50.0 km/hr towards train B, which moves at 30.0 km/hr toward train A on the same track.
>
> How much time (in hours) do they have before the trains collide?

I tried visualize the graph of the delta X for both trains and see the intercept point but i didn't know what's the equation of the graph would be i tried many method but none of them had the right answer .

Can someone give a brief explanation of every step to solve this problem ?

Comment: Divide the initial separation by the relative speed

Comment: But is there any explanation why ?

Comment: [Galilean relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_invariance)

Comment: @Maroxtn It's straightforward: $x_A(t)=50t$ and $x_B(t)=150-30t$ because it starts at $x=150$ and is going back, hence the minus sign. Equate these and you'll get the same answer, $t=1.875$.